# How to get pixel color of an image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am building an eyedropper. I want to retrieve the precise pixel color of an image that can be zoomed and dragged.

I tried using the code from https://gist.github.com/roipeker/9315aa25301f5c0362caaebd15876c2f and placed the image inside an InteractiveViewer widget. However, when I zoom in, the color I obtain by tapping on the image is not accurate.

my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

class ColorPickerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorPickerWidget(
      {super.key,
      required this.image,
      required this.color,
      required this.isColored});

  final Uint8List image;
  final ValueNotifier<Color> color;
  final bool isColored;

  @override
  State<ColorPickerWidget> createState() => _ColorPickerWidgetState();
}

class _ColorPickerWidgetState extends State<ColorPickerWidget> {
  GlobalKey imageKey = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey paintKey = GlobalKey();
  bool repaintKey = true;
  bool dirty = false;

  bool useSnapshot = true;

  late GlobalKey currentKey;

  img.Image? photo;


  final _stream = StreamController<Offset>();
  double kEyeDropperSize = 16;

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentKey = useSnapshot ? paintKey : imageKey;

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _stream.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final offsetNotifier = snapshot.data ?? const Offset(-10, -10);

        return Listener(
            onPointerDown: (details) {
             
              double dx = details.localPosition.dx - kEyeDropperSize / 2;
              double dy = details.localPosition.dy - kEyeDropperSize / 2;
              _stream.add(Offset(dx, dy));
            },
            child: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: [
              InteractiveViewer(
                maxScale: double.maxFinite,
                minScale: 1.0,
                onInteractionUpdate: (details) {
                  dirty = true;
                },
                onInteractionEnd: (details) {
                  dirty = true;
                },
                child: RepaintBoundary(
                  key: paintKey,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTapDown: (details) {
                      searchPixel(details.globalPosition);
                    },
                    child: Center(
                      child: Image.memory(
                        widget.image,
                        key: imageKey,
                        filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                        color: (widget.isColored) ? null : Colors.grey,
                        colorBlendMode:
                            (widget.isColored) ? null : BlendMode.saturation,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: offsetNotifier.dx,
                top: offsetNotifier.dy,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/color-picker-overlay.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  width: kEyeDropperSize,
                  height: kEyeDropperSize,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          
        );
      },
    );
  }



  void searchPixel(Offset globalPosition) async {
    if (repaintKey || photo == null || dirty) {
      dirty = false;
      await loadSnapshotBytes();
    }

    _calculatePixel(globalPosition);
  }

  void _calculatePixel(Offset globalPosition) async {
    RenderBox box = currentKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    Offset localPosition = box.globalToLocal(globalPosition);

    double px = localPosition.dx;
    double py = localPosition.dy;


    int pixel32 = photo!.getPixelSafe(px.toInt(), py.toInt());
    int hex = abgrToArgb(pixel32);
    widget.color.value = Color(hex);
    if (widget.color.value != Colors.transparent) {
      repaintKey = false;
    }
  }

  Future loadSnapshotBytes() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boxPaint =
        paintKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    ui.Image capture = await boxPaint.toImage();
    ByteData? imageBytes =
        await capture.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    setImageBytes(imageBytes!);
    capture.dispose();
  }

  void setImageBytes(ByteData imageBytes) {
    final values = imageBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
    photo = null;
    photo = img.decodeImage(values);
  }
}

// image lib uses uses KML color format, convert #AABBGGRR to regular #AARRGGBB
int abgrToArgb(int argbColor) {
  int r = (argbColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
  int b = argbColor & 0xFF;
  return (argbColor & 0xFF00FF00) | (b << 16) | r;
}
```